# How change the message on TextView of a custom Dialog Box?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I want to create a custom Dialog Box. Since I am a beginner, I used this link as a reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-custom-dialog-with-rounded-corners-in-android

However, I am unable to change the message in TextView programmatically since it depends on what the user selects. How can I do it?
I tried body_message.text = message (as described in the code below), but it doesn´t work. Thank you in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_dialog"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Success"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/body_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu erat tincidunt lacus fermentum rutrum."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
            android:text="Fechar"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val message = "testing message"

        findViewById<View>(R.id.customDialog).setOnClickListener { v ->
            val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity, R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
            val viewGroup = findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
            val dialogView: View = LayoutInflater.from(v.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, viewGroup, false)
            val buttonOk = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonOk)
            val body_message = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.body_message)

            body_message.text = message

            builder.setView(dialogView)
            val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            buttonOk.setOnClickListener { alertDialog.dismiss() }
            alertDialog.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my mistake after many attempts (I am still a beginner):

I used
val body_message = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.body_message)
where body_message is the TextView that I want to change the message, and dialogView is the Dialog Box. The only difference is that I added "dialogView". If I understood correctly, it makes the code correctly look for the TextView (named body_message) inside the Dialog Box.
It is working and I can change the message that is exhibited programmatically.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added more details in the answer to make it clearer.Still learning how to fully customize a Dialog Box, but learning step by step.